# Error when compiling Facebook Android SDK sample app

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, facebook-android-sdk

I followed this guide on official facebook developers site:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android-using-android-studio/3.0/

And when im trying to build first sample app im getting error:

```
Gradle: Error while executing dx command
Gradle: UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Gradle: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter$1;
Gradle: at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
Gradle: at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
Gradle: at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:490)
Gradle: at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
...
Gradle: 1 error; aborting
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':abcd:dexDebug'.
```

I think it happens because there is android-support-v4 included in facebook sdk, and my project somehow wants to include it too and i tried to remove it - but it didnt help.

My project's build gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
    compile project(':libraries:facebook')
}
```

facebook's sdk build gradle is the same as in linked manual.

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar issue, for me it was because I was using an external lib version of the support sdk which it appears you are too. You need to edit the build.gradle file in the facebook library to use the same support library.

dependencies {

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
//compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')  - As outlined by Facebook
```

}

Hope this helps.